# Can see databases and empty tables in hive but not on WEB UI filesystem

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I had an database named default and test user `/user/hive/warehouse/` and I was messing with `--delete-target-dir` in sqoop and unfortunately deleted both the databases so the tables are also gone.

Luckily I have everything backed and there was not much in those databases. So i tried to go create both the databases again and it says that databases with those names already exists. So I tried to see those databases and tables in hive terminal. I can see both the databases and all the tables in both the databases using `show databases;` and `show tables;` in hive but the tables are empty.

I also tried to use `desc database default` and the location it shows I can't see them on WEB UI file system.

Is there a way to get them back? or should I drop the databases and recreate them with tables?

I am using `Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.10.0`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

1. The data is gone, not the metadata.
   The database and tables definitions are still stored in the metastore, pointing to non existing locations.
2. If the trash feature is turned on, your data might still exist (moved to another location instead of deleted immediately).
   If it is, it would be under `/user/{The user who owned the data}/.Trash`.
   Check the values of `fs.trash.interval` and `fs.trash.checkpoint.interval`.

> **fs.trash.interval**
>
> Number of minutes after which the checkpoint gets deleted. If zero,
>   the trash feature is disabled. This option may be configured both on
>   the server and the client. If trash is disabled server side then the
>   client side configuration is checked. If trash is enabled on the
>   server side then the value configured on the server is used and the
>   client configuration value is ignored.
>
> **fs.trash.checkpoint.interval**
>
> Number of minutes between trash checkpoints. Should be smaller or
>   equal to fs.trash.interval. If zero, the value is set to the value of
>   fs.trash.interval. Every time the checkpointer runs it creates a new
>   checkpoint out of current and removes checkpoints created more than
>   fs.trash.interval minutes ago.
>
> https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml

Comment: I tried to go check under /user/hdfs/.Trash/Current/temp/(here I found 6 files) and all where of size 0B.

Comment: Check user `hive`

Comment: there is /user/hive/warehouse and then there should be the databases which I am missing.

Comment: No `/user/hive/.Trash`?

Comment: No such file or directory

Comment: When you are creating a table now, which user is the owner of the data?

Comment: the owner is cloudera

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148817/discussion-between-dudu-markovitz-and-dereck).